# RESTful Application with MVC Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-mobile, restful-architecture

Ok. So for school, we need to make a mobile app that works with a RESTful api that is programmed through a MVC architecture. I do know how the MVC architecture works, but I really don't understand how the RESTful thing works...

From what I've looked up (and asked around), I think to have understood that when you have a Restful application, A JSON string should be reproduced when you type a certain URL. For example 'www.website.com/users' should give me a list of all the users. 'www.website.com/users/johndoe' should give me the userpage of John Doe.

However...  I don't know how to begin with this... [This](https://github.com/OlivierParent/NMDADII_jqmobile) is the example our teacher showed us (so that's how it should be done). I just don't understand how you would give a certain layout to these pages.

Is there anyone that would be willing to take a look at this and explain it to me. I'm kinda desperate...

Thanks in advance,

HS.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a detailed post on the topic with lots of examples, which may be helpful:

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api